# Replace special character

Tags: mysql, update, syntax, replace

I am trying to replace the character `'` with the character `"`, using:

```
UPDATE posts SET text = replace(text, ''', '"');
```

but:

> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>   Ending quote ' was expected. (near "" at position 59)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL accepts ' and " interchangeably.  So use ' to quote " and " to quote ':

```
REPLACE(text, "'", '"')
```

(There are many other solutions, involving hex, conversions, etc, but the above seems simple and straightforward.)

But...  The error message does not look like a MySQL error, so I suspect your query is in a quoted string in your client language.  So...

What client language?  Does it use backslash (`\`) for escaping things?